# Setting types of parsed values in Antlr

Tags: antlr4

I have a rule that looks like this:

```
INTEGER : [0-9]+;
myFields : uno=INTEGER COMMA dos=INTEGER
```

Right now to access uno I need to code:

```
Integer i = Integer.parseInt(myFields.uno.getText())
```

It would be much cleaner if I could tell antler to do that conversion for me; then I would just need to code:

```
Integer i = myFields.uno
```

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

You could write the code as action, but it would still be explicit conversion (eventually). The parser (like every parser) parses the text and then it's up to "parsing events" (achieved by listener or visitor or actions in ANTLR4) to create meaningful structures/objects.

 Of course you could extend some of the generated or built-in classes and then get the type directly, but as mentioned before, at some point you'll always need to convert text to some type needed.

Answer (score 0):

A standard way of handling custom operations on tokens is to embed them in a custom token class:

```
public class MyToken extends CommonToken {
    ....
    public Integer getInt() {
        return Integer.parseInt(getText()); // TODO: error handling
    }
}
```

Also create

```
public class MyTokenFactory extends TokenFactory { .... }
```

to source the custom tokens. Add the factory to the lexer using `Lexer#setTokenFactory()`.

Within the custom `TokenFactory`, override the method

```
Symbol create(int type, String text); // (typically override both factory methods)
```

to construct and return a new `MyToken`.

Given that the signature includes the target token type `type`, custom type-specific token subclasses could be returned, each with their own custom methods.

Couple of issues with this, though. First, in practice, it is not typically needed: the assignment var is statically typed, so as in the the OP example,

```
options { TokenLabelType = "MyToken"; }

Integer i = myFields.uno.getInt(); // no cast required
```

If Integer is desired & expected, use `getInt()`. If Boolean ....

Second, ANTLR options allows setting a `TokenLabelType` to preclude the requirement to manually cast custom tokens. Use of only one token label type is supported. So, to use multiple token types, manual casting is required.

Comment: Is there a way to force this to extend only the tokens that are integers?